# How to execute a query according to a given parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, select

¡Hi!

I'm trying to build a query that will fill a data set (GridView) according to a specific parameter. So if the parameter is 1 it should execute a SELECT statement A, and if it's 2, it should execute a SELECT statement B.

Here's my code so far:

```
DECLARE @p varchar(20) = '2018-02'
DECLARE @f1 int = 1
DECLARE @f3 int = 1

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @f3 = 1
        THEN
            (
                SELECT
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID],
                    [dbo].[N_Sedes].[Sede] AS [SedePrint],
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] + ' ' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] AS [NombrePrint],
                    CASE
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '1' THEN 'TI-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]  
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '2' THEN 'CC-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '3' THEN 'CE-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '4' THEN 'PP-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '5' THEN 'OT-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                    END AS [TipoDocIdentidadPrint],
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre] AS [Programa],
                    SUBSTRING([dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre])) AS [ProgramaPln],
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[Tipo],    
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[CodigoTemporal],
                    CASE
                        WHEN 
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])   
                            ) = 0
                        THEN '<article style="color: rgb(237,27,47)"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sin activar</article>'
                        ELSE '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activada</article>'
                    END AS [EstadoCuenta],
                    CASE
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'False' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuevo</article>' 
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'True' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(15,134,137)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Revisado</article>' 
                    END AS [Revisado1Print],
                    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Icono] + ' ' + [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Estado] AS [EstadoAdm],  
                    CONVERT(varchar(200), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[FechaEnv], 106) AS [Fecha],  
                    '<a href="inscripciones-detalles.aspx?sklid=' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) + '">Detalles</a>' AS [AClink],
                    CASE
                        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])) = '0'
                        THEN '<span class="textoRojoSm"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> N/A</span>'
                        ELSE '<span class="textoVerdeSm"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>(' 
                                + 
                                    CONVERT
                                        (varchar(200), 
                                            (
                                                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])
                                            )
                                        ) 
                                + ')</span>'
                                + ' <div class="tooltip">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[Codigo] FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '<span class="tooltiptext">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Comentario] + CONVERT(varchar(50), [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[FechaEnv]) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '</span></div>'
                    END AS [Seguimiento]   
                FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master] 
                    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[IdPrograma] 

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos] 
                    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Tipo] 

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision] 
                    ON [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[ID]       

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[N_Sedes]
                    ON [dbo].[N_Sedes].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede]

                WHERE
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @p) 
                    AND
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede] = @f1)
                    AND
                    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) > 0)

                ORDER BY
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID] DESC,
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] ASC,
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] ASC
        )
    ELSE
        (
            SELECT
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID],
                    [dbo].[N_Sedes].[Sede] AS [SedePrint],
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] + ' ' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] AS [NombrePrint],
                    CASE
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '1' THEN 'TI-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]  
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '2' THEN 'CC-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '3' THEN 'CE-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '4' THEN 'PP-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '5' THEN 'OT-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
                    END AS [TipoDocIdentidadPrint],
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre] AS [Programa],
                    SUBSTRING([dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre])) AS [ProgramaPln],
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[Tipo],    
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[CodigoTemporal],
                    CASE
                        WHEN 
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])   
                            ) = 0
                        THEN '<article style="color: rgb(237,27,47)"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sin activar</article>'
                        ELSE '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activada</article>'
                    END AS [EstadoCuenta],
                    CASE
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'False' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuevo</article>' 
                        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'True' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(15,134,137)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Revisado</article>' 
                    END AS [Revisado1Print],
                    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Icono] + ' ' + [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Estado] AS [EstadoAdm],  
                    CONVERT(varchar(200), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[FechaEnv], 106) AS [Fecha],  
                    '<a href="inscripciones-detalles.aspx?sklid=' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) + '">Detalles</a>' AS [AClink],
                    CASE
                        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])) = '0'
                        THEN '<span class="textoRojoSm"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> N/A</span>'
                        ELSE '<span class="textoVerdeSm"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>(' 
                                + 
                                    CONVERT
                                        (varchar(200), 
                                            (
                                                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])
                                            )
                                        ) 
                                + ')</span>'
                                + ' <div class="tooltip">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[Codigo] FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '<span class="tooltiptext">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Comentario] + CONVERT(varchar(50), [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[FechaEnv]) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '</span></div>'
                    END AS [Seguimiento]   
                FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master] 
                    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[IdPrograma] 

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos] 
                    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Tipo] 

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision] 
                    ON [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[ID]       

                INNER JOIN
                    [dbo].[N_Sedes]
                    ON [dbo].[N_Sedes].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede]

                WHERE
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @p) 
                    AND
                    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede] = @f1)
                    AND
                    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) = 0)

                ORDER BY
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID] DESC,
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] ASC,
                    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] ASC
        )
    END;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 84
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 156
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
```

Both queries have the same table structure in columns, but will render different data according to the last statement in the WHERE clause.

So if parameter @f3 = 1 that statement will be:

```
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) > 0)
```

And if @f3 = 2 that statement will be:

```
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) = 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Be very careful here. You are creating a performance timebomb. You are trying to achieve what is known as multiple execution paths. There are some things you can do to help but you need to know how to deal with it correctly. Fortunately Gail Shaw has a great blog about this here. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error because, You `select` multiple columns in one column.

You can try `IF` instead of `CASE WHEN`

```
IF  (@f3 = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID],
    [dbo].[N_Sedes].[Sede] AS [SedePrint],
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] + ' ' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] AS [NombrePrint],
    CASE
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '1' THEN 'TI-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]  
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '2' THEN 'CC-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '3' THEN 'CE-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '4' THEN 'PP-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '5' THEN 'OT-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
    END AS [TipoDocIdentidadPrint],
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre] AS [Programa],
    SUBSTRING([dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre])) AS [ProgramaPln],
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[Tipo],    
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[CodigoTemporal],
    CASE
        WHEN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])   
            ) = 0
        THEN '<article style="color: rgb(237,27,47)"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sin activar</article>'
        ELSE '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activada</article>'
    END AS [EstadoCuenta],
    CASE
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'False' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuevo</article>' 
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'True' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(15,134,137)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Revisado</article>' 
    END AS [Revisado1Print],
    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Icono] + ' ' + [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Estado] AS [EstadoAdm],  
    CONVERT(varchar(200), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[FechaEnv], 106) AS [Fecha],  
    '<a href="inscripciones-detalles.aspx?sklid=' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) + '">Detalles</a>' AS [AClink],
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])) = '0'
        THEN '<span class="textoRojoSm"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> N/A</span>'
        ELSE '<span class="textoVerdeSm"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>(' 
                + 
                    CONVERT
                        (varchar(200), 
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])
                            )
                        ) 
                + ')</span>'
                + ' <div class="tooltip">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[Codigo] FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '<span class="tooltiptext">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Comentario] + CONVERT(varchar(50), [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[FechaEnv]) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '</span></div>'
    END AS [Seguimiento]   
    FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master] 
    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[IdPrograma] 

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos] 
    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Tipo] 

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision] 
    ON [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[ID]       

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[N_Sedes]
    ON [dbo].[N_Sedes].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede]

    WHERE
    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @p) 
    AND
    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede] = @f1)
    AND
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) > 0)

    ORDER BY
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID] DESC,
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] ASC,
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] ASC
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID],
        [dbo].[N_Sedes].[Sede] AS [SedePrint],
        [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] + ' ' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] AS [NombrePrint],
    CASE
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '1' THEN 'TI-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]  
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '2' THEN 'CC-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '3' THEN 'CE-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '4' THEN 'PP-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[TipoDocIdentidad] = '5' THEN 'OT-' + [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad]
    END AS [TipoDocIdentidadPrint],
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre] AS [Programa],
    SUBSTRING([dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Nombre])) AS [ProgramaPln],
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[Tipo],    
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[CodigoTemporal],
    CASE
        WHEN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])   
            ) = 0
        THEN '<article style="color: rgb(237,27,47)"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sin activar</article>'
        ELSE '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activada</article>'
    END AS [EstadoCuenta],
    CASE
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'False' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(121,162,68)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuevo</article>' 
        WHEN [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Revisado1] = 'True' THEN '<article style="color: rgb(15,134,137)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Revisado</article>' 
    END AS [Revisado1Print],
    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Icono] + ' ' + [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[Estado] AS [EstadoAdm],  
    CONVERT(varchar(200), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[FechaEnv], 106) AS [Fecha],  
    '<a href="inscripciones-detalles.aspx?sklid=' + CONVERT(varchar(max), [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) + '">Detalles</a>' AS [AClink],
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])) = '0'
        THEN '<span class="textoRojoSm"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> N/A</span>'
        ELSE '<span class="textoVerdeSm"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>(' 
                + 
                    CONVERT
                        (varchar(200), 
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID])
                            )
                        ) 
                + ')</span>'
                + ' <div class="tooltip">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[Codigo] FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '<span class="tooltiptext">' + (SELECT TOP(1) [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Comentario] + CONVERT(varchar(50), [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[FechaEnv]) FROM [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc] INNER JOIN [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento] ON [dbo].[N_Insc_EstadosSeguimiento].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[Codigo] WHERE([dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[IdPre] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID]) ORDER BY [dbo].[N_Seguimiento_Preinsc].[ID] DESC) + '</span></div>'
    END AS [Seguimiento]   
    FROM [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion]

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Master] 
    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[IdPrograma] 

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos] 
    ON [dbo].[N_Programas_Tipos].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Programas_Master].[Tipo] 

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[EstadosAdmision] 
    ON [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Estado] = [dbo].[EstadosAdmision].[ID]       

    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[N_Sedes]
    ON [dbo].[N_Sedes].[ID] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede]

    WHERE
    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @p) 
    AND
    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede] = @f1)
    AND
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) = 0)

    ORDER BY
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[ID] DESC,
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Apellido] ASC,
    [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Nombre] ASC
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If only one `where` condition is different then you are writing redundant code using `if-else` condition as query is almost same. It will be hard to maintain in future and prone to bugs. You should consider removing `if-else` condition and handle @f3 condition in `where` clause with single query. Last statement of updated `where` clause will look like below.

Remove this statement -

```
        ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])) = 0)
```

and replace it with below condition

```
        (@f3=1 and  exists (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])
        OR
        (@f3=0 and  not exists (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])
```

Your final Where clause will look like below -

```
WHERE
    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Periodo] = @p) 
    AND
    ([dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[Sede] = @f1)
    AND
    (   (@f3=1 and  exists (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])
        OR
        (@f3=0 and  not exists (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] WHERE([dbo].[aspnet_Users].[UserName] = [dbo].[N_Preinscripcion].[DocIdentidad])
    )
```